# Getting a unique DOM reference to each item of an ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

My ng-repeat directive is of the nature:

```
<div ng-repeat = "i in items track by $index"> 

    <mydirerctive attr1 = {{i.attr1}}, attr2={{i.attr2}, ng-click="displayMenu(i)"} > </mydirective>

</div>
```

The `displayMenu` function is supposed to display a menu based on the selected item. In order to determine the position at which the menu should be rendered, I should have a unique DOM reference to point to each item (for eg, a unique id ). How do i get each item in `ng-repeat` to get a unique id?

Comment: Why not just use `$index`?

Comment: @MWay : $index is not a reference to the DOM for each item, it's just  a number.

Comment: Yes, but it is a number unique to each item, which is what you are asking for.

Comment: @MWay: Sorry, I meant a unique pointer to each element in the DOM. With just a number, it's not possible to identify where the item belongs in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

angular provides you a $event object if you write your ng-click in this way:

```
ng-click="displayMenu($event,i)"
```

From the $event you have access to the element that triggers the click event. Just log the $event by console.log($event)...

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, your `displayMenu` function should be part of the directive itself, if it is required to act on the same DOM elements. So instead of using `ng-click`, watch for the click event manually inside the directive, either through `.on()` or by using a directive template which includes `ng-click`. Then you only have to pass in the appropriate menu information.